# Is a graceful reload idempotent for ansible?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, provisioning, ansible

We're now investigating Ansible to provision our servers. It's quite a default nginx, php-fpm & mysql setup. However, I am wondering about installation of these packages and how to make the playbook idempotent with the services running.

For nginx, we've a default `nginx.conf` and some files in `conf.d/`. For php, we've a `php.ini`, a `php-fpm.conf`, a pool in `pool.d/` and some ini files in `conf.d/`. Is it the idea to overwrite all files on every ansible playbook call?

If all configurations are overwritten, is it OK to do a `service nginx reload` and `service php5-fpm reload` even when the server is under heavy load? For initial installations, a `reload` will not start the server, so I have to check the status first and based on that, switch between `start` and `reload`?

If I look for playbooks with a nginx installation, they often use handlers which will restart nginx. However, this is not graceful, so I don't really like that approach:

```
service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

In general, **what's the common pattern to use ansible and provision servers with services** like nginx, php-fpm and mysql **without forcing a restart**?

Answer (score 5):

The [service module can do reload](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html#options) with `state=reloaded`.

Configuration file won't be uploaded if the same version is already on the server. Thus, reload won't be triggerer if you use `service: name=nginx state=restarted` in a handler.

You can also use `service: name=nginx enable=yes` so the service starts at boot (and thus there is no need to explicitely `start` nginx, only `reload` if needed).

Answer (score 4):

On the #ansible IRC channel I got already an answer which works. The pattern in general for apt systems is that the service is started after an install. So you can omit the `start` completely and only `reload` in cases when configs change.

The setup would then be (as example, Nginx is taken)

1. Install Nginx
2. Overwrite all config files
3. If in #2 something changed, run a reload

This should be sufficient; when Nginx is not installed, steps 1,2 and 3 are executed. When Nginx is installed and the configs are OK, no reload happens. If we update the configuration, step #2 is causing a change so a reload happens.

This should be sufficient to cover all cases.

Comment: Even though on apt systems service might auto start, you still want to explicitly say that. For example if a package is installed but the service does not automatically start on bootup. You want to use `service` module to make sure that all relevant services are in correct states.